# Build tag sets from interesting tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-watching, tag-filters

I already have a lot of tags marked interesting. 
Would it be possible to reuse these when creating custom tag sets?
I just noticed these can be imported, but there's no easy way to partition them.

For example, I'd like a more focused view on some nosql questions, or some language questions that exclude the more active tags. 
Something drag-and-drop based would be very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist exactly as you want, but I think the workaround is pretty easy:

1. Create a new tag set
2. Import your interesting tags using the button
3. Delete tags until you get it down to a partition you want
4. Name the tag set something appropriate
5. Repeat steps 1 - 4 until you have your interesting tags split up into several tag sets.